# Django: Wrong URL pattern? View doesnt get called.

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a project with a few apps, one of them is called blog. I'm trying to render a page for each single blogpost.

**models.py**     (MyProject/Blog/Models)

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=40, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
```

**views.py**     (MyProject/Blog/Views)

```
def get_blog(request, blog_id):
    print "THIS STRING IS A TEST"
    blogpost = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    context = {'blogpost': blogpost}
    return render(request, 'blog_page.html', context)
```

**urls.py**    (MyProject/Urls)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'app_1.views.home', name='home'),    
    url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$','blog.views.get_blog'),
```

]

One of my blogposts has the following uuid: *98bfad8b-c44c-41d0-98d0-158379c3e362*
Yet when I go to "example.com/BLOG/*98bfad8b-c44c-41d0-98d0-158379c3e362*", nothing happens.
It also doesn't print out 'THIS STRING IS A TEST', which tells me the view doesn't even get called.
It's my first time dealing with non-static URLS. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url regex is wrong `\d+` any digit ( `0 through 9` ) so you have to make sure your regex capture `words` and `-`.

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>[^/]+)$', 'blog.views.get_blog'),
```

You have to make sure `blog` is pointing to that particular view..

Comment: Thanks Raja, this brings me one step closer, however this doesn't call my viewfunction.

Comment: It will definitely call your view function ... pls see the updated url

Comment: The view doesn't even get called, no teststring output, nore does it render a new page. Perhaps the uuid type i use has a different format? --> 'default=uuid.uuid4'..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100011/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-gunth223-ha).

Answer (score 1):

write your url like this:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<uuid>\w*)$', 'blog.views.get_blog'),
```

set blogpost variable like this:

```
blogpost = Blog.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
```

and pass the hex of your uuids to it